Number of time digit $3$ will appear while writing all the numbers from $1000$ to $9999$

Number of time digit $3$ will appear while writing all the numbers from $1000$ to $9999$

My Approach:
Case $1$ $3$ appear only once
Subacse $1$:
$3,\_,\_,\_,\_$ total number of times $3$ will appear is $9\times9\times9=729$
Subcase $2$:
$\_,3,\_,\_$ total number of times $3$ will appear is $8\times9\times 9=648 $
also in this case there are total of $3$ possibility so total answer to this subase is $648\times3= 1944$
Case 2:
Digits $3$ appear two times
Subase 1:
$3,3,\_,\_$ there are total of $2\times 9\times 9=162$ times digit $3$ will appear
Subase 2:
$3,\_,3,\_$  answer to this question is also $162$
Subcase 3:
$3,\_,\_,3$ answer to this case is also $162$
Subase 4:
$\_,3,3_\_$ answer to this case is $8\times9\times 2=144$
there will be 2 more cases so answer to this subcase is $144\times=432$
Case $3$:
$3$ appear three times
Subase $1$:
$3,3,3,\_$ answer to this case is $3\times 9=27$
and there are two more possibility here $3,\_,3,3$ or $3,3\_3$
Hence answer to this case is $3\times9\times3=81$
Subcase $2$:
$\_,3,3,3$ answer to this case is $8\times 3=24$
Case $4$:
Digit $3$ appear four times for example $3,3,3,3$
so answer to this case is $4$
My final answer:
$3700$
Also this is not homework quesition it was given to me by friend he want to teach it to 12th grade students in tomorrow class
Now I don't know whether it is correct or not?
ALso is there any other method to solve this problem which can be applied for any interval for example between $153$ to $1893$ how many times $3$ will appear?

Where did this question come from? Is this your homework? Please give context for this question [tour]

Applying an adaptation of the method here will get you a general answer.

Easiest is to construe the problem as a probability problem.
There are exactly $~9000~$ numbers that have $~4~$ digits, where the leftmost digit is not allowed to equal $~0.$
The leftmost digit will randomly run through $~\{1,2,\cdots,9\},~$ while the other $~3~$ digit places will each randomly run through $~\{0,1,2,\cdots,9\}.~$
Therefore the total number of occurrences of the letter $~3~$ is
$$9000 \times \left[ ~\frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{10} ~\right]$$
$$= 1000 + \left[ ~3 \times 900 ~\right] = 3700.$$

For the interval $~153~$ through $~1893~$ inclusive, things are a little tougher.
From the previous analysis, you know that the number of occurrences of the number $~3~$ in the range $~1000~$ through $~1899~$ inclusive is
$$ 900 \times \left[ ~\frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{10} ~\right] = 280.$$
Further, the digit $~3~$ does not occur anywhere in the range of $~1894~$ through $~1899~$ inclusive.
Similarly, the number of times that the digit $~3~$ occurs in the range $~100~$ through $~999~$ is also
$$~900 \times \left[ ~\frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{10} ~\right] = 280.$$
So, the number of ways that $~3~$ occurs in the range $~153~$ through $~1893~$ inclusive equals
$$560 - x$$
where $~x~$ equals the number of occurrences of $~3~$ in the range $~100~$ through $~152~$ inclusive.
Then $~x = 10 + 5 = 15.$
So, the final tally is
$$560 - 15 = 545.$$

+1, although that's finicky to generalize.

@CameronBuie Agreed, re the gymnastics I had to go through for the (just added) trailer to my answer.

There are $10^3$ numbers in that range with $3$ in the leading position.
There are $9\times 10^2$ numbers in that range with $3$ in any of the other three positions.  Thus there are
$$10^3+3\times 9\times 10^2=3700$$
$3's$ in total.

This is clearly the best answer, in my humble opinion.

Here's a fun way to calculate this using probability. Let's choose a random number from $1000$ to $9999$; and let $X$ be the number of threes in said number. Then
$$X = X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4$$
Where $X_i$ is the random variable which is $1$ if the $i$-th digit is $3$ and $0$ otherwise. Then
\begin{align}\mathbb EX&= \sum_{i=1}^4\mathbb P(X_i=1)\\\\&=\frac19+\frac1{10}+\frac1{10}+\frac1{10}\\\\&=\frac{37}{90}\end{align}
But we also have
\begin{align}\mathbb EX&=\sum_{i=1}^4i\mathbb P(X=i)\\\\&=\frac1{9000}\sum_{i=1}^4i\#\{\text{numbers with } i\;3\text{'s}\}\end{align}
Therefore, the number we're looking for is
$$9000\mathbb EX=3700$$

It's important to notice that we don't strictly need probability. This has an interpretation with averages, just using that the average is linear, as well as a counting argument. This way it's just tidier

If you search same question for any interval, you can go step by step.
How many digits 3 do we need to write all numbers between 153 and 1893 ?
In the column of units, we can search an interval with length a multiple of 10.
In this case, from 153 to 1892 (be careful, the interval [a,b] has a length b-a+1.
The length of this interval is 1892-153+1=1740 ; In this interval, the digit 3 appears 174 times in last column.
So it appears 175 times in last column in the original interval.
Then, for 2nd column we need an interval with a length that we can divide by 100. : from 153 to 1152 ; length is 1000 ; every 10th digit is a 3. So 100 digits 3 is this range.
Plus 10 digits 3 between 1230 and 1239, 10 other digits between 1330 and 1339 ... 70 digits 3 in decimal-column, between 1153 and 1892.
$200$ digits 3 in cents-column.
Total is $200+170+174=544$.
Result take some time, but I think there is no faster method.

You said that $3$ appears $175$ times in the last column in the original interval, but you used $174$ in calculating your final answer.
